# Should a question lacking detail and clarity be reopened if we have an answer?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, story-identification

Lately, we've been getting a lot of two line [isekai](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/isekai) questions, seemingly hit-and-runs where the question is incredibly barebones and we seldom see the person again. For one of them, [Manga about a male student of magic who was killed by a noble, and reborn as a noble child](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/243173/manga-about-a-male-student-of-magic-who-was-killed-by-a-noble-and-reborn-as-a-n), I actually do know the answer, but only because I started reading it on my own, and recognized the premise. Is it worthwhile to vote to reopen a question that might never be accepted, that has not been improved, because an answer is known?

Comment: My opinion on these is wait for detail, you know something that sounds familiar but it's not necessarily correct and the question is still lacking detail so if you're wrong would likely only end up needing closing again anyway. Leave a comment with the possible answer and see if they accept it later on maybe.

Comment: {nods} It matches every detail. Both of them. X-D

Comment: The OP of that specific question was online just an hour ago, so there may still be hope of them seeing and accepting an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### In general

I'm going to say no. If a [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) question has been closed as lacking focus, the typical reason is that it potentially matches **lots** of properties. That you've managed to identify *one* of those properties (and presumably would like to post it as an answer) doesn't change the fact that the question is lacking focus.

***Unless...***

If you post a comment mentioning a property that matches their crappy description and OP confirms that *that's precisely what they were looking for all along*, in that case it seems churlish to leave it closed when there's a perfectly good (and correct) answer waiting to be posted.

---

### In specific

That particular question should be reopened. Although it's very terse, the presence of a fairly identifying fact (that the main character has a pet goat) should be sufficient to have it stand out from the crowd of other properties that match the Isekai Reincarnation trope

Comment: In principle a story ID question is closed as "locking focus" if it "matches **lots** of properties". In practice people vote to close terse ID questions with rather specific details that don't match **any** "properties" that I know of.

Comment: @user14111 - Yes, but they usually get reopened shortly afterward, if they can offer something that looks like a relative unique (or at least rare) piece of info. Terse doesn't have to mean lacking focus.

Comment: The point of closing questions with insufficient detail to identify "The" answer is that next time someone searches for exactly the same thing, it's very unlikely they're looking for the exact same answer, because the question is so vague it could be any of dozens. That someone happened to guess the "correct" answer for the first person asking doesn't mean they (or even anyone else) has guessed the correct answer for the second person, or the third, or... Leaving these questions closed is hardly churlish - it is perfectly good curation to uphold standards.

Comment: @Nij - Sure, if you consider upholding standards to be the be-all and end-all of why we're here. I, personally, think there's also something to be said for the fact that the reason why someone posts an ID question isn't to ask a good question, it's to identify the thing that they personally are trying to recall.